# Putting background-image beside an element

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` tag.

The tag is centered on the page in a div. I need to put decorative images beside it.

It has to look like this

```
-------------------------- h1 ----------------------------
```

If I do fixed images, it works fine. What I want, though is if I increase the size of h1 (by putting more text), the side shrink accordingly. Like this

```
------------------------ h1 h1 h1 ------------------------


 h1:before {
        background-image:url('../img/dual_bg.png');
        padding: 0 20px;
        content: " ";
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position-y: 50%;
        margin-right:20px;
    }
    h1:after {
        background-image:url('../img/dual_bg.png');
        padding: 0 20px;
        content: " ";
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position-y: 50%;
        margin-left:20px;
    }

    h1{
        text-align:center;
    }
```

As said, I get the desired result if I increase the padding value. However, I need a better approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

your solution is to add width style, try to use `max-width`, `min-width` and put it for the DIV, then use the padding for tag h1, and `use text-align: center` for the h1 also.

now when you add more text, the size of div will stay the same, and text will go on the same line with less padding.